# Jump to a specific date in Fullcalendar + Scheduler, but show only a specific range

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

On a page, I have a Fullcalendar + Scheduler and a search form with 2 inputs: `start-date` and `end-date`. When I submit it, an `ajax` call begins (I need to do some stuff on a server side), and I receive the dates in the `json`. What I need is to re-render the calendar that will begin and end with the dates from the `josn`. The code I have:

```
      var searchForm = $('#search-form');
      searchForm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/en/admin/search',
          data: {
            start_date: '2018-06-01',
            end_date: '2018-07-01'
          }
        }).done(function (data) {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', data.start_date);
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            validRange: {
              start: data.start_date,
              end: data.end_date
            }
          });
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        });
      });
```

`'gotoDate'` function is workinb, but the `validRange` doesn't work in the callback. I also tried to add `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');`, but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong, and what can be done to solve this issue? Thanks ahead.

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            validRange: {
              start: data.start_date,
              end: data.end_date
            }
          });` is basically re-creating your calendar with minimal options. You don't want to do that I don't think. If you need to set options after the calendar was first created, then use this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

Comment: Thanks a lot, just added `'option'` into a `fullCalendar()` function, and it did what I needed.